# onMessage event is never called

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So I am working on my next add-on for Firefox, however, while reading the documentation for ContextMenus, it appears that the onMessage event is never being called, here's my code:

```
exports.main = function(){
    var addonTab = require('addon-page');
    var data = require('self').data;
    var tabs = require('tabs');
    var cm = require("context-menu");

    cm.Item({
        label: "Tag This Image",
        context: cm.URLContext("*"),
        contextSelector: "img",
        contentScript: 
            'self.on("click", function(node, data){' +
            '   self.postMessage(node);' +
            '});',

        // nothing works...
        onMessage: function(node){
            openImageEditor(node.src);
            alert("Message? It worked? No way!"); 
            onTagImage(node);
        }
    });

    var onTagImage = function(node){
        alert("Image tagged!"); 
    };

    tabs.open({url: data.url('index.html'), isPinned:true});
};
```

So I take a look at the Error's Console, but this probbaly the worst kind of error format I've ever seen ...

> Timestamp: 14/07/2012 3:21:44 Error: An exception occurred. Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/context-menu.js",
>   line 1310, in CMP_handleEvent
>       this.*handleClick(event.target);   File "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/context-menu.js",
>   line 1339, in CMP*_handleClick
>       this.browserWin.fireClick(topLevelItem, popupNode, item.data);   File
>   "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/context-menu.js",
>   line 1162, in BW_fireClick
>       worker.fireClick(popupNode, clickedItemData);   File "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/context-menu.js",
>   line 663, in CMW_fireClick
>       this._contentWorker.emitSync("click", popupNode, clickedItemData);   File
>   "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js",
>   line 71, in emitSync
>       return this._emitToContent(Array.slice(arguments));   File "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/content-worker.js",
>   line 96, in onChromeEvent
>       return emit.apply(null, args);   File "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/content-worker.js",
>   line 45, in onEvent
>       results.push(callback.apply(null, args));   File "javascript:self.on("click", function(node, data){
>   self.postMessage(node);});", line 1, in null   File
>   "resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/content-worker.js",
>   line 81, in onEvent
>       let str = JSON.stringify(args, replacer); [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
>   [nsIImageLoadingContent.loadingEnabled]"  nsresult: "0x80040111
>   (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/cuddlefish.js
>   -> resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/sandbox.js
>   -> resource://jid0-dxglsws2k0cubycbcn7cw5tcyqk-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/content-worker.js
>   :: onEvent :: line 81"  data: no]

Here's the actual line, but this isn't making any sense to me:

> File "javascript:self.on("click", function(node,
>   data){self.postMessage(node);});", line 1, in null

Question: What does this error mean, or what is exactly wrong with the said line?

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery's `.on()` without actually having jQuery loaded?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'm using the on() event from the firefox-addon-sdk, whether that's the jQuery one from within the addon itself, idk, but I believe that's not the issue, I have however an idea why this might have happened, I believe the "self" reference isn't a global one but one that I'll have to assign myself, will try when I get back at it.

Comment: I can reproduce it - your context-menu implementation looks a little strange though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context-menu implementation was a little screwy in a few ways, see this fixed example:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1065630/latest/

1. the postMessage call from the content script cannot send the html node, it can only send JSON data.
2. don't use alerts in main.js or other modules loaded from ./lib/ - alert is not defined here. Use console.log instead.
3. the context you need is context: cm.SelectorContext('img')

Comment: Thanks! It works now :)

#3: What's the difference between this and my current code?

Comment: my code posts a string via postMessage, your code posts a node reference. postMessage can only send basic types, eg anything that can be serialized into JSON.

Comment: Is 'contextSelector: "img"' as a part of the options object even valid code? for context, you need to supply a single context or an array of contexts. See the docs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/addon-kit/context-menu.html#context

Comment: It is valid, well at least it works for me, while the other way didn't work last time.